# Unable to completely remove Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have used sudo apt-get purge thunderbird* and sudo updatedb . After locate -e , I still see thunderbird files like below; How can it be solved? Thanks in advance

```
/home/keeceng/.thunderbird/4sq64m28.default/virtualFolders.dat
/home/keeceng/.thunderbird/4sq64m28.default/webappsstore.sqlite 
/home/keeceng/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/InstallTime20150112185638 
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/thunderbird:thunderbird.desktop 
/usr/share/app-install/icons/thunderbird.png 
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
```

Comment: You need to manually delete them. User config files inside home folders are never removed by apt-get. All in all, I think it's been completely removed according to the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command to remove the configurations and other things in your home:

```
rm -rf /home/keeceng/.thunderbird
```

Do not remove the following files. These files come from other packages:

- from package `app-install-data`

  ```
  /usr/share/app-install/desktop/thunderbird:thunderbird.desktop
  /usr/share/app-install/icons/thunderbird.png
  ```
- from package `gnome-accessibility-themes`

  ```
  /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
  ```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thx and improved :)

Comment: To you too. Have an upvote.